# VB.net how to create table using xml and displaying the table on the webpage

Tags: xml, vb.net, sql-server-2005

Can somebody please help me to amend this code because i tried running but the table didnt appear on the page. I'm new to XML and somebody gave me this snippet saying that XML coding is more reliable for tables.

The code probably works but i dont know how to display it to the page. I tried searching but i saw that many also did nearly the same thing but why didnt it work for me? While, some others made another xml file to keep the data, but in my case, i'm actually planning to retrieve data from a MS SQL 2005 database and display it in a table. What am i missing here?

```
Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData()
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim tr As XElement = <tr></tr>

        For Each column In dt.Columns
            Dim td As XElement = <td></td>
            td.Value = row(column.Ordinal).ToString()

            tr.Add(td)
        Next

        table.Add(tr)
    Next
```

=================================================

For each column in a row and the subsequent rows, the time should iterate by 30 minutes. in each row, there should be 3 columns so for example value for

(0,0): 6.00am aaaa (0,1) 6.30am bbbb (0,2) 7.00am cccc

(1,0) 7.30am dddd  (1,1) 8.00am eeee (1,2) 8.30am ffff

for the rest of the day's schedule

===========================================
AFTER MODIFICATION

My plan is to display the table and at the same time, when the user clicks on the available time(free/not occupied), the user will be able to request an appointment for that certain time and thus an insert to database query will be executed

I did as you suggested. I also rearranged the loop so that the column loop is on the outside and the row loop on the inside. I did this so that the data are displayed only once instead of a repetition of each new column in each new row. I've edited my code as shown below so its easy for you to understand what i did.

Your time increment didnt work for me so I've tried modifying a bit and this one worked. But the problem is the time displayed at the first column of the first row is the last time iterated in the loop(that is 11:00:00 am - because i queried for 10 data). And its the same time displayed at the last column of the row. The database value of the first and the last are also the same. So in other words, only 9 data are retrieved and displayed. Why is this happening?

```
 Public Function DrawTable() As XElement
  Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData()
  Dim table As XElement = <table></table>
  Dim tr As XElement = <tr></tr>
  Dim td As XElement = <td></td>
  Dim dtTime As DateTime = #6:00:00 AM#
  Dim timeN = dtTime

  For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows      
    For Each column In dt.Columns         
        td.Value = dtTime.ToString() + " "  + row(column.Ordinal).ToString()
        dtTime = dtTime.AddMinutes(30) 
        timeN = dtTime            
        tr.Add(td)
    Next

    table.Add(tr)
  Next
 Return table
 End Function
```

Below is how the table should should look like

```html
<table style="border:solid">
<tr>
<td style='border:groove'>6.00 AM aaaa </td>
<td style='border:groove'>6.30 AM bbbb </td>
<td style='border:groove'>7.00 AM cccc </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='border:groove'>7.30 AM dddd </td>
<td style='border:groove'>8.00 AM eeee </td>
<td style='border:groove'>8.30 AM ffff </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='border:groove'>9.00 AM gggg </td>
<td style='border:groove'>9.30 AM hhhh </td>
<td style='border:groove'>10.00 AM iiii </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='border:groove'> ... </td>
<td style='border:groove'> ... </td>
<td style='border:groove'> ... </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='border:groove'>5.00 AM fffe </td>
<td style='border:groove'>5.30 AM sefs </td>
<td style='border:groove'>   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where did you define table object?

Comment: The GetData function is declared as a DataTable. Do i have to put a placeholder in the page as the table object?

Comment: check my answer.
I define table object at first.

Comment: Can i put a placeholder in the page as the table object? If yes, then what can i put as the initializers? PlaceHolder3.Controls.Add(New Table() With {})  Or if this is unapplicable, could you please suggest a better idea? Sorry but i'm stumped

Comment: I really don't recommend you to play with placeholder. table as XElement is a good idea in your case.

Comment: I tried running with the modifications but it still didnt work.

Comment: so you want to render a <table> in your page which is getting data from DataBase?

Comment: hopefully yes. my plan is when the user chooses an option from a dropdown list and few several textboxes then clicked a button, the table would be displayed as a daily time schedule based on the chosen values. 
The column of a row would be filled with values if there is a data from the database that fits the time(so the time is not available), and leaves the column of the row as blank if there is no data(so the time is available/free).

Comment: check my answer please. add your comments there. thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Public Function DrawTable() As XElement
    Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData()
    Dim table As XElement = <table></table>
    Dim tr As XElement = <tr></tr>
    Dim td As XElement = <td></td>
    Dim dtTime As DateTime = #6:00:00 AM#

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For Each column In dt.Columns
            dtTime = dtTime.AddMinutes(30) 
            td.Value = dtTime.ToString() + " " row(column.Ordinal).ToString()
            tr.Add(td)
        Next

        table.Add(tr)
    Next
    Return table
End Function
```

use this in your .aspx page will render Table

```
    <%= DrawTable()%>
```

Comment: Wow! It works! Thanks a bunch! :D But is there any way to make the data presented in the table normally? because now it looks like a staircase and the values of some of the columns are redundant >.<

Comment: Oops sorry..i just realized that i actually have to re-structure the for each loop.

Comment: I just tried to implement 2 values into the td.Value but i see that only the last td is executed. Because my plan is to put a time in each row(column). so i did td.Value = row(column).ToString()   
td.Value = time . it didnt work-only the last td is executed.. so i tried putting <td> in a different variable tdOpen=<td> and tdClose=</td> in order in insert another string variable beside the data from the database(that is, in between the <td></td>) Example: | 8.30am aaaa | 9.00am bbbb | is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: in fact the way you decide to render your data-table into table object is very old fashion. I hope you can get off this method. so angularJs would be very useful.

Comment: so now you want to add extra <td> to keep date and time within each row. am I right?

Comment: haha i guess i have a traditional way of thinking then. thanks for your suggestion. i'll have a look at it :)

Comment: if possible, for each row's column. as in, for each column in a row and the subsequent rows, the time should iterate by 30minutes. in one row, there should be 3 columns so for example value for (0,0): 6.00am ; (0,1) 6.30am; (0,3) 7.00am; (1,0) 7.30am; (1,1) 8.00am ....for the rest of the day's schedule

Comment: now we have this : td.Value = row(column.Ordinal).ToString() . then we will add to <tr> object by this : tr.Add(td) 
then we can add another td like : td.value = "7.30am" and add that to tr as well

Comment: on second thought, i think i'll have to reject using angularjs because the webpage i'm working on right now is one that will be used by hundreds of users and it involves important data transactions and money related so implementing js is quite dangerous right? and unreliable for those not having javascript enabled.

Comment: it does work but for all rows of the first column, it only shows the time without the database value. i queried for 5 data but only 4 out of 5 data are shown in the table. whereas, the time is being displayed 6 times.

Comment: While we have security solution and in your case you want to get data and show to users it doesnt make sense rejecting Angular.

Comment: I cant answer in comment properly so please edit your question and include new requirment. Then I can edit mine as well.

Comment: sorry my bad. its just that for my other module in the incoming future, i have to implement a credit card transaction, etc. as for that, can i apply angularjs too? for the meantime, in my current module, my plan is to display the table and at the same time, when the user clicks on the available time(free/not occupied), the user will be able to request an appointment for that certain time and thus an insert to database query will be executed

Comment: AngularJs is very good while you have an Api project that feed Angular with Json and then can easily play with data by angular. This is my experience as a .NET developer after switching to AngularJs and single page application concept.

Comment: I did as you suggested. I also rearranged the loop so that the column loop is on the outside and the row loop on the inside. I did this so that the data are displayed only once instead of a repetition of each new column in each new row. I've also edited my code for the iteration of time but there is a problem with the time displayed. I've edited my question for more details. Hope you could help me check it.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I retried putting the forEach row on the outside and the forEach column on the inside and putting a do-loop-while loop in between the forEach and now it works. Thanks for your help anyways :D

Comment: I just realized that the time column values are only correct for the first column but it doesnt for the subsequent columns.And the data values for the columns are redundant for each rows. I think my problem is because the rows and columns are generated based on the data resulted from a query. Whereas, what i'm trying to achieve actually is the columns and rows should already have been generated beforehand holding the values of the time in one-day with 30 minutes interval spanning each columns and rows. based on the time displayed, then a query will be executed.sorry if i made this complicated

Comment: I've updated my question with a table snippet showing what i mean. sorry for the confusion. The time value should be co-existent in the columns and rows, then only the values from the database be displayed if the appointment has been made for that certain time; if not, the column would be blank.